# How to prediction more than one images after training model with keras?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I want to try to predict an image after I have trained with my model.

With the code below I can only predict one image, how can I predict more than 50 images for example?

**Example code**

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

test_image = image.load_img('dataset/test_image/girls.jpg', target_size = (64, 64))
test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
result = classifier.predict(test_image)
training_set.class_indices
if result[0][0] == 1:
  prediction = 'nsfw'
else:
  prediction = 'sfw'

print(prediction)
```

Can you tell me what I should change or add to the code?

Maybe you have a reference code to predict more than one image you could share?

Answer (score 0):

To batch predict a directory of 50 images you could follow this example [here](https://androidkt.com/how-to-predict-images-using-trained-keras-model) and do the following:

```
batch_holder = np.zeros((50, IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE, 3))
img_dir='test_set/'
for i,img in enumerate(os.listdir(img_dir)):
  img = image.load_img(os.path.join(img_dir,img), target_size=(IMG_SIZE,IMG_SIZE))
  batch_holder[i, :] = img
```

where in your case `IMG_SIZE = 64`.
Then you can just call the method `predict_classes()` of the `model` object:

```
classes = loaded_model.predict_classes(batch_holder)
```

There is also this [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/ritiek/5fa903f97eb6487794077cf3a10f4d3e) that does it with a similar way.

Comment: i tried the code from github and i got this error ""OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = '/models/model.h5', errno = 2, error message = 'No such file or directory', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)
' "" even though the location of directories and files is put on the right place

Comment: Is the script located in the same folder where '/models/model.h5' is? Try using the absolute path to be sure.

Comment: yes, I'm sure the location of the script file is the same as the model and dataset folder

but it still gives me the same error

Comment: Make sure that there is a model.h5 file in the models folder (this may sound too obvious but you never know) and if indeed there is, try to load it without the '.h5' extension.

Answer (score 0):

What would you like your output to be? This sounds like it could be done with a simple for loop. You can probably do it more efficient in Keras, but taking a simple approach this also works. The code below takes all images in the folder of `dataset/test_image` and creates a list with classifications in order of the `image_list`:

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import os

image_folder = 'dataset/test_image/'
image_list = os.listdir(image_folder)
classifier_results = []
for image in image_list:
    test_image = image.load_img(image_folder + image_list[image], target_size = (64, 64))
    test_image = image.img_to_array(test_image)
    test_image = np.expand_dims(test_image, axis = 0)
    result = classifier.predict(test_image)
    training_set.class_indices
    if result[0][0] == 1:
      prediction = 'nsfw'
    else:
      prediction = 'sfw'
    classifier_results.append(prediction)
    print(image_list[image], "is classified as: " prediction)
```

Comment: actually i want downward output like 
nfsw 
sfw 
sfw 
nfsw 
etc .... 
yeah like that, until the number of images that I want.

but sir, i tried for your code and im getting an error

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'load_img'

what should i do?

Comment: I've updated the snippet above a bit so it also takes the folder name into account in `image.load_img`, but highly recommend to follow some basic Python tutorials before you dive into Keras.

Answer (score 0):

```
from imutils import paths
imagePaths = list(paths.list_images('test'))

for test_image in imagePaths:

   result = classifier.predict(test_image)
```

Comment: Provide more context to your answer. This does not say why you would use the code